# Is it possible to export reading time data in Perusall?

Tags: export, csv

I am using [Perusall](https://perusall.com) to organize a university course. I want to export each student's average reading time in csv or other table format. Is it possible to do that? If yes, how? I can download a table with students' names and emails but there's no data about reading time.